# Calculating Aerosol optical thickness from Landsat 7

Tags: geoprocessing, remote-sensing, landsat, map-algebra

**EDIT I have added question down**
I am reading one paper and I found method to retrive AOT from landsat 7 image[image][image]
This should be simplifield equation, because they assumed observation zenit as 0. Than they put on landsat image grid cell 20x20. 
So have they calculated standard deviation for each cell and than with this equation they should get AOT also for each cell. Am I correct? 
**EDIT** And at the end if I have AOT for first cell I just put in raster calc [raster1] * AOT1

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article? It'll help with the understanding and context of the equation.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen I have added more. Cant find paper on internet. I have just saved it....

Comment: The equation is taken from the thesis [Mapping of Dispersion of Urban Air Pollution Using Remote Sensing Techniques and Ground Truth Data](http://www.itc.nl/library/papers_2003/msc/gfm/wijeratne.pdf) by I.K. Wijeratne, submitted 2003 to ITC, Enschede.

Comment: Yes. Your understanding of the text appears to be correct. They split the land-pixels into 20x20 areas, calculate the standard deviations for both the "clear" day and the "polluted" day and use that to determine the AOT for the "polluted" day - under the assumption that the "clear" day has an AOT of 0.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen and AOT will be between 0 - 1 and also different for each cell in the 20x20 grid

Comment: Mathematically, it doesn't have to be between 0 and 1. However, in most cases it likely will be. You should possibly implement a fix to remove potential negative values, which occurs if sigma-2 is bigger than sigma-1. And yes, each cell 20x20 cell has its own AOT, which is the whole point. Note that the approach assumes no changes in the surface between the two images, which is a risky assumption.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen  thanks, I have learned something usefull.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen last question if I have AOT for one part of grid. Now I sholud just in raster calc. [raster1] × AOT1 ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Atmospherically corrected data, or?

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen I have monitoring stations and if I want to do correlation or regression between aot and data from stiations I need to pick AOT at the place where station is.

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything in raster calculator. Just take the AOT for a gridcell where you have a station and correlate away.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen yes but equation 4.5 takes standard deviation in grid cell. Also I have calculate standard deviation and aot for this cells. Now I have aot 2.041 for 40x40 pixels

Comment: You calculate the standard deviation in each 20x20 / 40x40 grid cell for both the clear day and the polluted day. Then put those in eq4.5 and that gives you AOT for each grid cell. Then you compare the AOT from the area where your station is, to your station data from the polluted day.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen so I dont calculate AOT for each pixel. But only for each cell of my grid...Than I will have 1600 pixels (40x40 grid) with same AOT

Comment: That is correct. Varying AOT a 30m scale is not something often done. In most cases the spatial variability in the atmosphere is not at that scale (usually and barring small scale polluters, such as single smokestacks from factories etc.)

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen  also good idea, to use it on smokestacks